# Eclipse Eclipse is running under 1.6, but 1.7 is needed

Tags: java, eclipse, version

I have just installed WindowBuilder for Eclipse and java 1.7 JDK, but when I create a new JFrame in Eclipse, and try to open the "design-view" in WindowBuilder I get the following error: "Eclipse is running under 1.6, but the Java project has a 1.7 Java compliance level, so WindowBuilder will not be able to load classes from the project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version."
How to Resolve Incompatible Java version Error in Eclipse in mac?

Answer (score 1):

You might have installed the Java 1.7 SDK but it looks like Eclipse is started with the older one (1.6).
The WindowBuilder is integrated into Eclipse and will use the same Java instance as Eclipse (that is the 1.6 version).

However your project will use Java 7. The WindowBuilder (Java 6) will be unable to load classes from the higher version which your project uses (Java 7).

What you need to do is:
Configure your eclipse to start with the newer (Java 7) version. This can be done in the [Eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file.

Comment: and how can i config my eclipse under mac?                                   -startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.101.v20120109-1504
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

Comment: -startup
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
../../../plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.cocoa.macosx.x86_64_1.1.101.v20120109-1504
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
-vmargs
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-Xdock:icon=../Resources/Eclipse.icns
-XstartOnFirstThread
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.internal.carbon.smallFonts

Comment: The key is that `-vm` option in the file. That should point to the JDK 1.7 installation. Please check that `/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java` path if it is correct

Comment: I think yes because if : eduroam-106-113:jdk1.7.0_51.jdk sajad$ cd /Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/
eduroam-106-113:bin sajad$ ls
appletviewer java  jcmd  jmc  jstatd  policytool servertool
apt  javac  jconsole jps  jvisualvm rmic  tnameserv
extcheck javadoc  jdb  jrunscript keytool  rmid  unpack200
idlj  javafxpackager jhat  jsadebugd native2ascii rmiregistry wsgen
jar  javah  jinfo  jstack  orbd  schemagen wsimport
jarsigner javap  jmap  jstat  pack200  serialver xjc
eduroam-106-113:bin sajad$

Comment: `/Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version` will print you the Java 7 version?

Comment: eduroam-106-113:bin sajad$ /Library/java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)
eduroam-106-113:bin sajad$

Comment: If that is in the `eclipse.ini` of the eclipse you're actually starting, that would mean, that it uses the right java version. That would mean that the problem is to be found somewhere else and my approach was wrong. As a workaround you can set the project to be complient with Java 6. `Project -> Settings -> Java Compiler -> Compiler compliance level = 1.6` but that is a workaround, not a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Which Eclipse you're running? 
You definitely need to upgrade your Eclipse to a newer x64 Version to use Java 1.7.0